# How the code output is different when you compute it mentally? when the j = 2 the output should be 1, but the computer display 3

Tags: c++

I was searching a method to print a pascal triangle, but when I tried to compute mentally it doesn't look right.

the output of this is 1   3   3   1.
but when you mentally calculate the iteration one by one the output is 1   3   1   0.
is there something that I was missing?

```
        #include <iostream>
        using namespace std;

        int main()
        {
           coef = 1;
           int i = 3;
           int j = 0;

             while (j <= i)
             {
               if (j == 0)
                 coef = 1;
               else
                 coef = coef * (i - j + 1)/j;
  
               cout << coef << "   ";

               j++;
             }


            return 0;
        }
```

Comment: The answer is clearly that you didn't compute it mentally correctly. Without knowing how you came to your conclusion, it may be hard to give you any advice. You can try to step through the code with a debugger and see what value each variable has for each iteration.

Comment: `1/j` is 0, so the final multiplication gives 0.

Comment: SO Usage Note: Only pick one language Standard tag. If you don't care, leave it out entirely.

Comment: @PeteBecker yeah the final multiplication gives 0 when I calculate it. but when I run it the final output on computer is 1, I don't get it.

Comment: `3*(3-2+1)/2` is `3` and `3*(3-3+1)/3` is `1`? Seems like the computer is correct to me?

Comment: @AlanBirtles thanks for point that out what I am missing, I assume the coef variable values is always 1.

Comment: If you have access to a debugger you should step through the code 1 line at a time and see where the result does not match what you expected. You may want to write down your results on paper first so when you are debugging you have no confusion where and when the difference occurs. Make sure you number each line executed on your paper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mental computation is bit wrong as I am sure you are not updating the value of "coef" mentally which is being changed to 3 rather than 1 which you seem to have missed after the 2nd iteration of the loop.

Comment: yes you right, thank you for point that out, I assume the coef variable is always 1.